# In SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Script Wizard, Files to generate does not appear

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

In SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Script Wizard, I'm trying to export each database object to a separate single file but `Files to generate` does not appear under Script To File options.

I'm sure I did it before and it is there but it does not show up in mine

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Enterprise Manager? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/343f2cec-9cb8-40e5-b3ac-3304b6154cfd/ suggests that the feature is gone.

Comment: Look at 4th picture in 
http://earljon.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/sql-server-2005-scripting-each-objects-to-a-separate-file/

The option is there, but it won't show in mine right now!

Comment: If I recall (probably incorrectly) there are separate versions of management studio from the Express and non-Express installation media. Perhaps yours is SSMS Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Files To Generate` does not exists in MS SQL Server 2005 and is added in SP2.
Installing SP3 or SP4 will not add it.

If you installed SP3 or SP4 you will not be able to install SP2 anymore.

You need to remove MS SQL Server 2005 and reinstall it and then install all service packs by number.

you can check version of Service pack that is currently installed by using:

```
select serverproperty('productlevel')
```